# How to get the tkinder text box/Entry box entered comma separated value into python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have the tkinder application  with multi tab
In that I need at 3rd Tab one Text box will be there. If user entered the value as 100,200,300 like comma separated. Then this should be converted as list and print.

Also I need one space between textbox and button

I have tried the below code. But not working. Pls help.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from tkinter import messagebox
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
import time
import re

win = Tk()
win.geometry('640x480')

#Set the Title of Tkinter window
win.title("Test Tab")
# Create a notebook that holds the tabs
notebook = ttk.Notebook(win)

# Create tab frames
tab1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
tab4 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
costcenter_value = StringVar()
# Add the tab frames to the notebook
notebook.add(tab1, text="TAB1 Test")
notebook.add(tab2, text="TAB2 Test")
notebook.add(tab3, text="TAB3 Test")
notebook.add(tab4, text="TAB4 Test")

notebook.pack(expand=1, fill='both')


   

def print_value():
    inp = value_entered.get(1.0, "end-1c")

    ***here I need to store the value into variable & display in screen which ever user entered into List*** 
    ## Example List_value = list(value_entered.get()

    lbl.config(text = "Provided Input: "+(inp))
   
def  Year_SelectionEvent(value):
    if value == '2024':
        print('Selected 2024')
    elif value == '2023':
       print('Selected 2023')

# Change the Version label text
def  Version_SelectionEvent(value):
    if value == '1.0':
        print('Selected 1.0')
    elif value == '2.0':
       print('Selected 2.0')
  

Label(tab3, text="Enter the list value  Details in comma separated!", font=('Helvetica', 10, 'bold')).pack()
value_entered = Text(tab3,height = 3,width = 50)
value_entered.pack()
Button(tab3, text='Show the Entered list values', command=print_value,bg='black', fg='white').pack()
lbl = Label(tab3, text = "")
lbl.pack()
Label(tab3, text="Choose the Year!",font=('Helvetica', 10, 'bold')).pack()
OPTIONS=["2024", "2023"]
year_clicked = StringVar(win)
year_clicked.set(OPTIONS[0])
year_selected = OptionMenu(tab3, year_clicked, *OPTIONS,command = Year_SelectionEvent).pack()
Label(tab3, text="Choose the Version!",font=('Helvetica', 10, 'bold')).pack()
OPTIONS=["1.0", "2.0"]
version_clicked = StringVar(win)
version_clicked.set(OPTIONS[0])
version_selected = OptionMenu(tab3, version_clicked, *OPTIONS,command = Version_SelectionEvent).pack()       


def dwonalod():

    print('Hello')
    //Perform some custom oerpation

Button(tab3, text='Download', command=dwonalod,bg='black', fg='white').pack()


win.mainloop()
```

I am getting console output as

`['1', '0', '0', ',', '2', '0', '0', ',', '3', '0', '0']`

and UI

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
List_value = value_entered.get().split(",")
```

For the UI:

```
inp = value_entered.get("1.0", "end-1c").split(",")
lbl.config(text="Provided Input: "+str(inp))
```

This will assume the user always enters the data in the format: number,number,number

It doesn't check for any other incorrect values.

As for the missing space, you can pack your button with the `pady` argument to create space between widgets.

```
Button(tab3, text='Show the Entered list values', command=print_value,bg='black', fg='white').pack(pady=5)
```